# Write a program that takes as input an array of positive and negative numbers (0 excluded)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, target

Write a program in java that takes as input an array of positive and negative numbers (0 excluded). The objective is to
return those items from the array whose sum is 0. If no such items exist return “No Elements found”
Example: For an input array [-4, 1, 3, -2, -1],
one of the possible results would be 3, -2, -1 since their sum is 0.
Note: If there are more than 1 combination of such items, you can return any 1 of them

its my try

```
class Solution {
   
        public int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
    int[] result = new int[2];
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (map.containsKey(target - numbers[i])) {
            result[1] = i;
            result[0] = map.get(target - numbers[i]);
            return result;
        }
        map.put(numbers[i], i);
    }
    return result;
}}
```

but I can't find the Ans can anyone help me out

Comment: Have you checked the "two sum" solutions? It's a pretty popular coding question and this one seems to go into that direction

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive solution:

```
public static int[] twoSum(int[] numbers) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean found = twoSum(numbers, 0, 0, list);
    if (found) {
        return list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
    }
    return null;
}

public static boolean twoSum(int[] numbers, int from, int target,
        List<Integer> list) {
    for (int i = from; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        int current = numbers[i];
        list.add(current);
        int newTarget = target-current;
        if (newTarget == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        boolean found = twoSum(numbers, i+1, newTarget, list);
        if (found) {
            return true;
        }
        list.remove(list.size()-1);
    }
    return false;
}
```